# R Reprojecting global forest change rasters

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, r, forest-ecology

I have been trying to calculate forest cover and forest loss in West Kalimantan Province, Indonesia, during 2000-2020. I use the gfcanalysis package in R for this purpose. Unfortunately, the minimum value of the forest cover raster turned to be -20 (minus) after reprojecting it to UTM 49 S, whereas the original value should be 0 (zero).

Following http://azvoleff.com/articles/analyzing-forest-change-with-gfcanalysis/, here are my codes to generate the output:

```
library('sp')
library('raster')
library('rgdal')
library('gfcanalysis')

// set working directory
setwd("D:/Users/GFC")
getwd()

// prepare output folder
output_folder <- "C:/Users/GFC/forestloss" 

// download boundary of West Papua Province (WPP) via GADM 
idn <- getData('GADM', country='IDN', level=1, download = TRUE) 

// inspect GADM and choose WPP
idn@data
idn <- idn[idn$NAME_1 == "Kalimantan Barat",] 

// reproject GADM to UTM 49S
idn.utm <- spTransform(idn, CRS("+init=epsg:32749"))
plot(idn.utm)

// calculate tiles needed to cover WPP
tiles <- calc_gfc_tiles(idn)
print(length(tiles)) 

// download GFC for WPP
download_tiles(tiles, output_folder)

// extract GFC data for WPP
gfc_extract <- extract_gfc(idn, output_folder, to_UTM=F, filename="GFC_extract.tif")

// reproject GFC
gfc_extract_utm <- projectRaster(gfc_extract, crs = "+init=epsg:32749")
gfc_extract_utm

// set forest threshold: 30%
forest_threshold <- 30

// thresholded GFC 
gfc_ extract_utm_th<- threshold_gfc(gfc_extract_utm, forest_threshold=forest_threshold, filename="gfc_ extract_utm_th.tif")

// calculate forest statistics 
gfc_statistics <- gfc_stats(idn.utm, gfc_ extract_utm_th)
```

Any idea what is happening?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I have revised my question. Hopefully, it's clear now.

Answer (score 0):

Reprojection involves interpolation- this almost always results in your destination values being different from your source values. This is explained well [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/220487/is-it-normal-that-the-values-of-a-raster-will-change-after-reprojecting-it) and [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/121646/what-resampling-technique-should-be-used-to-reproject-an-altitude-raster).

You need to take care to select an interpolation method that is appropriate for the type of data that you are working with. Since the default method for `projectRaster()` is `method='bilinear'` (appropriate for continuous variables), you might try `method='ngb'` (nearest neighbor; appropriate for categorical variables) instead and compare your result.

Below is a brief illustration:

```
#example data
r <- raster::raster(nrows=36, 
                    ncols=36, 
                    xmn=-121.6000, 
                    xmx=-121.5900, 
                    ymn=50.47000,
                    ymx=50.48000, 
                    resolution=0.0002778, 
                    crs = CRS('+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs'))

#set up some dummy values
r[]<-1:ncell(r)

r
# class      : RasterLayer 
# dimensions : 36, 36, 1296  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
# resolution : 0.0002778, 0.0002778  (x, y)
# extent     : -121.6, -121.59, 50.47, 50.48  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
# source     : memory
# names      : layer 
# values     : 1, 1296  (min, max)

#bilinear (default) interpolation - appropriate for continuous variables
b<-projectRaster(r, method="bilinear",crs = CRS('+proj=utm +zone=11 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0')) 

b
# class      : RasterLayer 
# dimensions : 45, 51, 2295  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
# resolution : 19.7, 30.9  (x, y)
# extent     : 173504.8, 174509.5, 5600849, 5602239  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# crs        : +proj=utm +zone=11 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs 
# source     : memory
# names      : layer 
# values     : -4.586387, 1291.587  (min, max)

#nearest neighbor interpolation - appropriate for categorical variables
n<-projectRaster(r, method="ngb",crs = CRS('+proj=utm +zone=11 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0')) 

n
# class      : RasterLayer 
# dimensions : 45, 51, 2295  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
# resolution : 19.7, 30.9  (x, y)
# extent     : 173504.8, 174509.5, 5600849, 5602239  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# crs        : +proj=utm +zone=11 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs 
# source     : memory
# names      : layer 
# values     : 1, 1296  (min, max)
```

Use caution though- it may be more appropriate to have max and min values that are "off" rather than using the wrong interpolation method for your type of data!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, Roman. I obtain comparable results after using the nearest neighbor approach as the interpolation method.